# Gaussian Process Regression with multiple variables: adaptation of kernels

Tags: python, scikit-learn, kernel, regression, gaussian

Ok, so I know this question already has been asked a lot, but I can't seem to find any explanatory, good answer to it. 
My question itself is simple: when performing gaussian process regression with a multiple variable input X, how does one specify which kernel holds for which variable?

An example will probably make this more clear. Look at the following code:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import ExpSineSquared, WhiteKernel, ConstantKernel

np.random.seed(0)

X = np.array([[0, 1, 2], [1, 3, 4], [2, 5, 1], [3, 7, 5], [4, 9, 7], [5, 0, 8], [6, 1, 2], [7, 3, 4], [8, 5, 1],
              [9, 7, 5], [10, 9, 7], [11, 0, 8], [12, 1, 2], [13, 3, 4], [14, 5, 1], [15, 7, 5],
              [16, 9, 7], [17, 9, 8]])

y = np.random.uniform(200, 300, len(X))

gp_kernel = 1**2*RBF(length_scale=[0, 0.01, 0]) * ExpSineSquared(0.02, 6, periodicity_bounds='fixed') + WhiteKernel()

gpr = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=gp_kernel, n_restarts_optimizer=2, normalize_y=True)
gpr.fit(X, y)

X1 = np.vstack((X, np.array([18, 3, 5])))
y_pred, sigma = gpr.predict(X1, return_std=True)

print(y_pred)
plt.plot(range(len(X)), y)
plt.plot(range(len(X1)), y_pred)
plt.show()
```

If you take a look at X, then you see that it's clearly periodic in the second dimension. I want to specify that, so my first attempt was something like this `ExpSineSquared([0, 0.2, 0], 6, periodicity_bounds='fixed')`, where I copied the approach of most of the answers I've found to this sort of question, and put 0 for variables for which the kernel does not hold. But sadly the ExpSineSquared doesn't allow an array as input for the `length_scale` parameter.

Therefore, I tried multiplying it with something that does allow this, for example the RBF, and looked at the results. That does give me some prediction, however if we change 
`gp_kernel = 1**2*RBF(length_scale=[0, 0.01, 0]) * ExpSineSquared(0.02, 6, periodicity_bounds='fixed') + WhiteKernel()` 
to `gp_kernel = 1**2*RBF(length_scale=[0.01, 0, 0]) * ExpSineSquared(0.02, 6, periodicity_bounds='fixed') + WhiteKernel()`, 
the result stays exactly the same, which can't be right (the first dimension is nowhere near periodic), so you'll expect some worse or at least different, result.

In short: if you have a multiple variable input and have constructed kernels that hold for some, but not all, variables, how does one specify which kernel holds for which variable?

Comment: An anistropic kernel should be the answer, I guess - I'm not an expert on Gaussian Processes. However, I can tell the example is flawed for two reasons: **1**) The `ExpSineSquared` is meant to model that *y* is periodic, not that *x* is periodic. **2**) The *y* data is completely independent from *x*; there is not much point in doing regression.

Comment: @kazemakase, regarding comment 1: Ok, that's a bit useful. However, what if we see 2 periods in the y-data which only hold for a part of the data (for example: weekdays and weekends are periodic, but you shouldn't compare the 2 with one periodic kernel). 
For comment 2: I know, but its sole purpose was to illustrate my point. :)

Comment: If you have two periods I think a sum of two periodic kernels is appropriate. If the periods are over different features you need anisotropic kernels, which is not supported by [`ExpSineSquared`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels.ExpSineSquared.html#sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels.ExpSineSquared) currently. I do not know if multiplying the isotropic periodic kernel with an anisotropic RBF results in the anisotropic periodic kernel that you need.

Comment: @kazemakase, I tried the sum already but I wasn't happy with the results. Doesn't there exist some Kronecker/Dirac delta kernel, that becomes one when comparing 2 of the same "days" (if we look at weekend/weekday relation) and 0 if you compare different ones? I know there's something like the dot product kernel, but I can't get it to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that the George package is extremely helpful in this case. First off, there are a *lot* more anisotropic kernels which you can use, so that's a big plus. Second, you can specify on which dimension they act. For example,  `ExpSquaredKernel(length_scale=1, ndim=4, axes=1)` is an RBF-kernel which acts on the second dimension (see axes parameter) of the. data which consists of 4 dimensions.